# 'Run' method giving "Invalid procedure call or argument" error

Tags: excel, macos, vba, powerpoint

Attempting to run the Sub "populateTextbox" in an open PowerPoint application from an Excel application (Office 2011) the following code works on my Windows machine:

```
Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application 

PPT.Run "MyPresentation.pptm!Module1.populateTextbox", slideNumber, collection
```

However on my Mac I get the error: *"Run-time error '5':
Invalid procedure call or argument"*

The Excel and the PowerPoint files are in the same folder and I have tried using the absolute path as well as the relative path above.

Comment: Update: I have tested that the run method works passing numbers, text, etc. But when I try to do it with a Collection that is what is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created an instance of PowerPoint prior to using the Run method?

```
Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
```